# Could not initialize class LoggerContext after upgrading to log4j 2.17.1

Tags: java, maven, log4j

I have just tried to upgrade the `log4j` library from version `2.3` to `2.17.1` to fix the well-known vulnerabilities that were discovered a few weeks ago. I am new to Maven, so I have little idea of what I am doing.

First, I changed my `pom.xml` project file and added all the `log4j` dependencies that I needed. I might have gone a little too far and only needed `log4j-core` and `log4j-api`, but just in case I added all of these:

```
...
<dependencies>
   ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>2.17.1</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.17.1</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.17.1</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.17.1</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.17.1</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
   ...
</dependencies>
...
```

After doing this, the project compiles successfully if I run `mvn clean package -U -Dmaven.test.skip=true`. However, **if I try to run the tests**, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.createContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:254)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:218)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:140)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:123)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:230)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:176)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:666)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getRootLogger(LogManager.java:700)
        at org.mycomp.myproj.utils.TestUtils.removeLogFile(Unknown Source)
        at org.mycomp.myproj.docs2tmx.AppTest.check(AppTest.java:48)
        at org.mycomp.myproj.docs2tmx.AppTest.testApp(AppTest.java:30)
```

I tried to modify the scope of the dependencies to `runtime` or `test`, but it does not seem to change anything. Do any of you know how to solve this? If you further loggings, don't hesitate to comment.

---

[EDIT]
Here is my `mvn dependency:tree -Dlog4j`:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] myproj_Docs2TMX
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building myproj_Docs2TMX 0.0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ myproj_Docs2TMX ---
[INFO] org.mycomp.myproj:myproj_Docs2TMX:jar:0.0.1
[INFO] +- org.mycomp.myproj:myproj_Utils:jar:0.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mycomp.processor:PLBase:jar:2.0.1myproj:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.mycomp.processor:PLogger:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.beust:jcommander:jar:1.48:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.googlecode.juniversalchardet:juniversalchardet:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ctc.wstx:woodstox-osgi:jar:3.2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.java.dev.stax-utils:stax-utils:jar:20070216:compile
[INFO] +- org.mycomp.processor:PLDocument:jar:2.0.1myproj:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tika:tika-core:jar:1.20:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tika:tika-parsers:jar:1.20:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.15:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.activation:javax.activation:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.gagravarr:vorbis-java-tika:jar:0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.tallison:jmatio:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.james:apache-mime4j-core:jar:0.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.james:apache-mime4j-dom:jar:0.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.18:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.epam:parso:jar:2.0.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.brotli:dec:jar:0.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:jar:2.0.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.pdfbox:fontbox:jar:2.0.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox-tools:jar:2.0.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.pdfbox:jempbox:jar:1.8.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk15on:jar:1.60:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.60:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.60:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-scratchpad:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.github.virtuald:curvesapi:jar:1.05:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.healthmarketscience.jackcess:jackcess:jar:2.1.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.healthmarketscience.jackcess:jackcess-encrypt:jar:2.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:jar:1.1.22:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.drewnoakes:metadata-extractor:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.adobe.xmp:xmpcore:jar:5.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- de.l3s.boilerpipe:boilerpipe:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.rometools:rome:jar:1.12.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.rometools:rome-utils:jar:1.12.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.gagravarr:vorbis-java-core:jar:0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codelibs:jhighlight:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.pff:java-libpst:jar:0.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.junrar:junrar:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-rs-client:jar:3.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:3.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:jar:3.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.openjson:openjson:jar:1.0.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- edu.ucar:netcdf4:jar:4.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- edu.ucar:grib:jar:4.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.itadaki:bzip2:jar:0.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:5.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.11.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- edu.ucar:cdm:jar:4.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- edu.ucar:udunits:jar:4.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:17.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- edu.ucar:httpservices:jar:4.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-csv:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.sis.core:sis-utility:jar:0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- javax.measure:unit-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.sis.storage:sis-netcdf:jar:0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.sis.storage:sis-storage:jar:0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.sis.core:sis-feature:jar:0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.sis.core:sis-referencing:jar:0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.sis.core:sis-metadata:jar:0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.opengis:geoapi:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- edu.usc.ir:sentiment-analysis-parser:jar:0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.uima:uimafit-core:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.uima:uimaj-core:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.bitbucket.mstrobel:procyon-compilertools:jar:0.5.32:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.bitbucket.mstrobel:procyon-core:jar:0.5.32:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jdom:jdom2:jar:2.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.pdfbox:jbig2-imageio:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.github.jai-imageio:jai-imageio-core:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mycomp:poi-sooxml-schemas:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:jar:3.25.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.mycomp.processor:PLModel:jar:2.0.1myproj:compile
[INFO] +- org.mycomp.processor:PLEngines:jar:2.0.1myproj:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mycomp:LanguageDetection:jar:0.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mycomp:aligner:jar:0.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:5.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:5.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-misc:jar:5.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.lmax:disruptor:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.jms:javax.jms-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.zeromq:jeromq:jar:0.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-stempel:jar:5.4.1:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j:pom:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:pom:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:pom:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api:pom:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:pom:2.17.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO]    \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] myproj_Docs2TMX ...................................... SUCCESS [  0.355 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.898 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-01-18T13:17:36+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 41M/1963M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It is a little bit trimmed to only show the information about the project that fails during the tests.

Comment: You should not use `<type>pom</type>`...

Comment: Could you comment a bit on why is that the case? I just copy/pasted the example at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j/2.17.1

Comment: It seems like you duplicated the log4j-core dependency. Could you show the results of ``mvn dependency:tree -Dlog4j`` to see if there's a conflict of some sort ?

Comment: It is a long output. I've just posted them here: https://pastebin.com/NhwH4xnB (I don't know if this is a good practice or if I should just add them to the question).

Comment: You could perhaps try removing the unnecessary dependencies. Does it work if you only include the log4j-core and log4j-api dependencies as shown in [this example](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html) ?

Comment: Sadly it did not work. It did not add any new errors, so I might keep it that way to keep my `pom.xml` clean. Furthermore, I cleaned up a little bit my dependency tree logs to focus on the project that actually fails. I added it to my question.

Comment: Your issue could stem from the transitive log4j dependency in myproj_Utils. Can you try excluding it in your pom to see if it works ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241172/discussion-between-zolastro-and-angela-lopez).

Comment: After messing around with it, i managed to solve it by excluding log4j from all the modules, and manually adding the new version as a dependence of each module instead of the global `pom.xml`. After doing that, all references to `log4j < 2.17.1` were removed